# Why Can't Eclipse locate source code for primitives and containers?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors

Maps, ArrayLists...etc don't appear to be available.

Problem started when I found out that my hadoop cluster was set to JDK 1.7, but my work station was set to JDK 1.8. I uninstalled JDK 1.8 and installed 1.7...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you remove and install different JREs, that doesn't automatically update Eclipse's `Installed JREs` preference page's entries, or references to them in your projects if they were referenced by name rather than by `Execution Environment`. You will need to go fix those up.

Comment: First go into the `Installed JREs` preference page and make sure you're only pointing at ones that are still installed. Then, in each project where you see this sort of issue, bring up the Properties dialog for its `JRE System Library` shown in the `Package Explorer` view. I'd suggest using the *Execution* *Environment* abstraction for JavaSE-1.7 so you don't have to go change it again later.